# Override/decorate javascript alert function

Tags: javascript, overriding, decorator

I would like to override the `alert()` Javascript function, while preserving 
its "focusing" behavior. I.e., customize the aspect, while bringing the focus to the browser tab where the popup is opened.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to directly customize/decorate the javascript alert box. What I would recommend doing is creating a custom alert modal, like the ones used by [twitter bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals).

It's been asked in [other stackoverflow questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7853130/how-to-change-the-style-of-alert-box) (this one recommends jQuery UI's modal).

This alone won't bring the focus to the browser tab where the popup opened though. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8135188/focus-tab-or-window) provides a decent solution for that that works with firefox, using window.focus().

Comment: Will the bootstrap alert set the focus on its own tab?

Comment: I edited my original answer. No, it doesn't focus the tab by itself, but you can use something like window.focus() in addition.