# Inconsistency in Focus Behavior when Opening a URL in a New Tab Using window.open()

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, url, browser

I am using the snippet below to open a URL in new tab

```
window.open(urlToOpen, '_blank', 'noopener noreferrer');
```

This part of code when hit for the first time, opens the URL in new tab but also shifts the focus to the new tab as well but all the consecutive clicks in the same session result in opening the URL in new tab but focus remains on the existing tab.
Based on my understanding, this particular part of snippet would have opened URL always in new tab and focus should not have shifted to new tab.

Is there any reason why this might be happening?(I have tried this across different browsers)

Comment: I've just tested from devtools with `$0.onclick = () => {   window.open('/', '_blank', 'noopener noreferrer');   }`, cannot reproduce. Please link a working page.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Post the code that calls the window.open function. And the browser.

Answer (score 1):

There is an old answer that suggests open the tab, close it and then open it again fixes the issue.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15247882/2087070

The problem is that focus on open tab only works when you open a new tab, not when you link to an already open tab in the browser, so closing and reopening it fixes the issue, as the browser then sees this tab as fresh.

Comment: Apparently that might cause bad user experience, right?

Comment: It’s a trade off with the negative user experience of not jumping to the opening tab. Whether that trade off is worth is for you app is going to depend on what your app does. II would suggest giving it ago and then deciding if it is worth it for your use case.